# return internal value function in a external function

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this code:

```
- (NSString *) login {

    datos=@"";

    NSString __block *variable;

    NSString *sqlQueryExisteUsuario;
    sqlQueryExisteUsuario = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE field='value' AND field='value'"];

    SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
    client.delegate = self;
    [client connect:@"serverName" username:@"username" password:@"password" database:@"database" completion:^(BOOL success) {

            [client execute:sqlQueryExisteUsuario completion:^(NSArray* results) {

            variable =   [self processLogin:results];

            NSLog(@"In: %@",variable);


            [client disconnect];


            }];

    }];    

    NSLog(@"Out: %@",variable);

    return nil;

}

- (NSString *)processLogin:(NSArray*)data
{

    existeArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray* table in data)
        for (NSDictionary* row in table)
            for (NSString* column in row)


                [existeArray addObject:row[column]];


    NSString *existe=existeArray[0];


    if([existe isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {

        datos=@"yes";

    }else{

        datos=@"no";

    }

    return datos;

}
```

In the first call to `NSLog`, which begins with `In`, the value shows. In the second call, which begins with `Out`, the value doesn't show. Why?

Comment: I had to read your code quite a few times to understand what you were trying to accomplish. It's important to understand that completion blocks (like you have two of here) only get run when their associated code completes, so iOS effectively jumps past them to get to the `NSLog()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your `connect` is async method, so `NSLog...` line will be executed earlier than `completion` block. So, you have to use blocks also:

```
- (NSString *) loginWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSString *result))handler
 {    
    datos=@"";

    NSString *sqlQueryExisteUsuario;
    sqlQueryExisteUsuario = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableName WHERE field='value' AND field='value'"];

    SQLClient* client = [SQLClient sharedInstance];
    client.delegate = self;
    [client connect:@"serverName" username:@"username" password:@"password" database:@"database" completion:^(BOOL success) {    
            if (success) {
                [client execute:sqlQueryExisteUsuario completion:^(NSArray* results) {

                    NSString *variable =   [self processLogin:results];
                    NSLog(@"In: %@",variable);                 
                    [client disconnect];
                    if (handler) {
                        handler (variable);
                    }
                }];
            } else {
                //TODO: handle this
                if (handler) {
                    handler (nil);
                }
            }
    }];    
}
```

Usage:

```
- (void)ff
{
    [self loginWithCompletion:^(NSString *variable) {
        //Do something with variable
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your variable is being set inside a completion block: the `variable` variable (not a great name, BTW!) is set inside not only one but two blocks - that's the "completion" part of your code – both of which are best thought of a bit(!) like a miniature anonymous function: in this case, they get run when the system is ready for it, not straight away.

iOS will start execution of your `connect` code, then jump ahead to `NSLog(@"Out: %@",variable)`, then execute the completion block of `connect`, which in turn starts more code (`execute`), which has its own completion block, which finally gets executed. As @rmaddy says in a comment below, the technical name for this is asynchronous code: the bit inside your block does not get executed immediately, which allows the system to continue doing other things while waiting for your task to complete.

So the running order will be:

1) You declare `variable`.

2) Your connection code starts.

3) `variable` gets printed out.

4) The connection completes.

5) Your `execute` code starts.

6) Your `execute` code completes.

7) `variable` gets set to the final value.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with blocks. The issue is that the `connect...` method is asynchronous.

Comment: I thought that was what I said; I shall re-read and try to clarify. (NB: I did try and simplify my phrasing because this seems like a fairly newbie-ish issue to encounter.)

Comment: 1) The first sentence states the problem is because of using a block. That is wrong. 2) You never once mention the word "asynchronous".

Comment: Thank you. 1) The first sentence might well have said that, but the second sentence says "that gets run when the system is ready for it." 2) I didn't use "asynchronous", no; I said "iOS will… jump ahead" as a way to explain the concept. I accept that my answer could have been clearer, and I have amended it following your advice.